# Python: how to loop through all unknown depth of a tree?

Tags: python, json

I have a strategic issue of writing a program doing a job.

I have CSV files like:

```
Column1  Column 2 
-------  ---------- 
parent1 [child1, child2, child3]
parent2 [child4, child5, child6]
child1  [child7, child8]
child5  [child10, child33]
...      ...
```

It is unknown how deep each element of those lists will be extended and I want to loop through them.

**Code:**

```
def make_parentClass(self):
        for i in self.csv_rows_list:
            self.parentClassList.append(parentClass(i))
        # after first Parent    
        for i in self.parentClassList:
            if i.children !=[]:
                for child in i.children:
                    for z in self.parentClassList:
                        if str(child) == str(z.node_parent):
                            i.node_children.append(z)
                            self.parentClassList.remove(z)
class parentClass():
    node_children = []
    def __init__(self, the_list):
        self.node_parent = the_list[0]
        self.children = the_list[1]
```

The above code might be a solution if I will find a way to iterate. Let me see if you like the question and makes sense now.

**Output:**

My aim is to build up a treeview through another language but first I need to make this output in JSON format. So the output expected to be something like:

```
{
  paren1:{'child1':{'child7':{}, 'child8':{}}, 
    'child2': {},
    'child3': {},
  },
  parent2: {
      'child4':{}, 
      'child5': {
          'child10':{},
          'child33':{}
      },
      'child6':{}
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The JSON posted in the answer does not correspond with the CSV, did you mean to use [] instead of {} for each child?. Also, to process each item, just use a recursive function once you have your data in the right format.

Comment: @h4z3 I was mostly thinking about a strategy to solve it. E.g. involving For loops which were not possible. I am also thinking about writing a function that loops back through itself but still can't say much how it looks like.

Comment: def process_item(self, item):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for i in item:
            process_item(item)
    else:
       do_something_with_item(item)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Code provided. Thanks

Comment: @Isma. The hard part is getting it "in the right format"

Comment: @jesy2013. I voted to reopen because you clearly put some effort into this, and I think this problem is interesting. However, your desired output does not make sense. For example, `child1:` starts a list, but there is no opening bracket. Could you please go through the output and fix it so it makes sense?

Comment: Also, `parent1:[{` opens two brackets, but only `]` is present after.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Thanks a lot for checking on this and finding the problem interesting. The JSON output was edited and now it is in a good format.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. Why are the leaves lists rather than dictionaries? I thought the children could be nested indefinitely. At the very least, shouldn't `'child7', 'child8'` be dict keys, not list elements? You can make a special exception for the values of `child2, child3` (for example), but that seems counter intuitive.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Now is good, right?

Comment: @jesy. Now is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a solution using two dictionaries. One nested one with the actually data structure you plan to convert to JSON, and one flat one that will let you actually find the keys. Since everything is a reference in Python, you can make sure that both dictionaries have the exact same values. Carefully modifying the flat dictionary will build your structure for you.

The following code assumes that you have already managed to split each line into a string `parent` and list `children`, containing values form the two columns.

```
json_dict = {}
flat_dict = {}

for parent, children in file_iterator():
    if parent in flat_dict:
        value = flat_dict[parent]
    else:
        value = {}
        flat_dict[parent] = json_dict[parent] = value
    for child in children:
        flat_dict[child] = value[child] = {}
```

Running this produces `json_dict` like this:

```
{
    'parent1': {
        'child1': {
            'child7': {},
            'child8': {}
        },
        'child2': {},
        'child3': {}
    },
    'parent2': {
        'child4': {},
        'child5': {
            'child10': {},
            'child33': {}
        },
        'child6': {}
    }
}
```

Here is an [IDEOne link](http://ideone.com/twvPdd) to play with.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually seems like a pretty good solution to me. I am going to test it. There is one structure I have to handle, that for me I have each row as ['parent', [child, child, child] but in your solution content is in a Tuple.

Comment: It is an elegant answer to me and quite fast but there is a simple issue E.g. if Child1 and its children be input of two parents, its children will appear in only one of the parents. e.g. add this ('parent3', ['child1', 'child2', 'child3'])

Comment: That's a completely different question from what you asked. Go ahead and select this answer, then all another with that condition in it.

Comment: OK I see. I will. Thanks.

Comment: Yes :). Thanks a lot for your help too overall.

Comment: @jesy2013. I'd recommend going through all your previous questions and selecting answers for them.

Comment: they were all checked :)