# How to assign children of a node wherever the node exist in the depth of a tree in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have data that describes a tree (parent - children). I want to build a JSON file based on it and assign children of a parent wherever the parent is found in the tree.

This problem is the extension of this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216064/1233240

**Code:**

```
file = [
     ('parent1', ['child1', 'child2', 'child3']),
     ('parent2', ['child4', 'child5', 'child6']),
     ('child1', ['child7', 'child8']),
     ('child5', ['child10', 'child33']),
     ('parent3', ['child1', 'child2', 'child3'])
]

json_dict = {}
flat_dict = {}

for parent, children in file:
    if parent in flat_dict:
        value = flat_dict[parent]
    else:
        value = {}
        flat_dict[parent] = json_dict[parent] = value
    for child in children:
        flat_dict[child] = value[child] = {}
```

**Current Output:**

```
{
    "parent1": {
        "child1": {
            "child7": {},
            "child8": {}
        },
        "child2": {},
        "child3": {}
    },
    "child1": {},
    "child2": {},
    "child3": {},
    "parent2": {
        "child4": {},
        "child5": {
            "child10": {},
            "child33": {}
        },
        "child6": {}
    },
    "child4": {},
    "child5": {
        "child10": {},
        "child33": {}
    },
    "child6": {},
    "child7": {},
    "child8": {},
    "child10": {},
    "child33": {},
    "parent3": {
        "child1": {},
        "child2": {},
        "child3": {}
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

I want all `child1` node like this:

```
"child1": {
    "child7": {},
    "child8": {}
}
```

but as we can see, only in `parent1` node it keeps its children.

Comment: So you don't want parent nodes?

Comment: I need all actually. I need to keep children of any node that found anywhere in the tree.

Comment: Are you sure that things are always named as parent and child? There's an easy hack that you might be missing here buddy.

Comment: I just named them as Parent and Child for clarification, otherwise they all come with a specific ID.

Comment: Are you sure that you want all your child nodes at the root too?

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Based on my experience of handling the website, I haven't seen another post that answers my question. 
As for the check mark, honestly I can't find it where it is. I just see the Vote buttons not check mark. 
Surely I don't need the child nodes with children to be in the root but I was planning to handle that by myself if I will have solution for the main problem. So I was thinking maybe I leave more confusion if I will add that point too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you wanted.

**Code**:

```
relations = []
for k,l in file:
    for v in l:
        relations.append((k,v))
pop_list=[]
items = {}
for parent, child in relations:
    parent_dict = items.setdefault(parent, {})
    child_dict = items.setdefault(child, {})
    if child not in parent_dict:
        parent_dict[child] = child_dict
    pop_list.append(child)
for child in pop_list:
    if child in items.keys():
        items.pop(child)
print(items)
```

**Output:**

```
{'parent1': {'child1': {'child7': {}, 'child8': {}}, 'child2': {}, 'child3': {}}, 'parent2': {'child4': {}, 'child5': {'child10': {}, 'child33': {}}, 'child6': {}}, 'parent3': {'child1': {'child7': {}, 'child8': {}}, 'child2': {}, 'child3': {}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a simple modification to the linked answer, to check if a child is already present, and use the existing object.

```
json_dict = {}
flat_dict = {}

for parent, children in file:
    if parent in flat_dict:
        value = flat_dict[parent]
    else:
        value = {}
        flat_dict[parent] = json_dict[parent] = value
    for child in children:
        if child in flat_dict:
            value[child] = flat_dict[child]
        else:
            flat_dict[child] = value[child] = {}
```

In both cases, the code can be shortened using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), but I normally wouldn't use that, since it creates an empty dictionary instance even when that's not necessary:

```
json_dict = {}
flat_dict = {}

for parent, children in file:
    if parent in flat_dict:
        value = flat_dict[parent]
    else:
        value = json_dict[parent] = flat_dict[parent] = {}
    for child in children:
        value[child] = flat_dict.setdefault(child, {})
```

While the second solution performs some potentially unnecessary operations, the code does look much clearer.

An alternative that is equally clean but with fewer unnecessary objects uses [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

json_dict = {}
flat_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for parent, children in file:
    if parent in flat_dict:
        value = flat_dict[parent]
    else:
        value = json_dict[parent] = flat_dict[parent]
    for child in children:
        value[child] = flat_dict[child]
```

Aside from requiring an import, this solution will not print as cleanly as a regular-`dict` based one. However, that will not affect the conversion to JSON in any way.

Since you commented that you don't actually want child nodes in the root, the snippets shown here will only place parent nodes in root. They will not, however, remove a node from root if you find out that it is a child later on. This can be accomplished with another simple modification, shown here for the `defaultdict` example, but applicable to all others as well:

```
from collections import defaultdict

json_dict = {}
flat_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for parent, children in file:
    if parent in flat_dict:
        value = flat_dict[parent]
    else:
        value = json_dict[parent] = flat_dict[parent]
    for child in children:
        value[child] = flat_dict[child]
        json_dict.pop(child, None)
```

Here is an [IDEOne link](http://ideone.com/kmrYxk) with the final answer.

Keep in mind that this code will not check for circular references. A circular reference will automatically remove itself from the result. For example:

```
file = [
    ('A', ['B']),
    ('B', ['C']),
    ('C', ['A']),
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solutions and explanation. All seems good and both answers are very good. But after running more tests, non of your code could bypass that test when I appended this data: ('child9', []) ,('child8', ['child9','B','C']). 
The issue is that when root node 'child9' later becomes a child, it won't be removed by other codes. In the last code you mentioned this case and it removes it but it will bring up other children up to the root nodes. e.g. 'child2' and 'child5'. But all those possibility worked with @lazycoder solution.

Comment: @jesy2013. Thanks for catching that. I've made a number of fixes to my code. I was trying too hard to shorten the code without considering consequences. There shouldn't be any more missing corner cases.

Comment: Thanks for that. it is also nice short solution.